# Python: How to join a list of string that contain quotes without escaping inner quotes?

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have a list of strings I'm trying to join into a single string:

```
["<a href='https://jira.abc.com/browse/abc-123456' target='_blank'>'abc-123456'</a>", "<a href='https://jira.abc.com/browse/abc-1234567' target='_blank'>'abc-1234567'</a>"]
```

I'm joining these with: `issuestr = ','.join('"%s"' % i for i in issues)`

When I `print(issuestr)`, I get:

```
jiraissues = {"JIRA Issue": issuestr}
print(jiraissues)
>>> {'JIRA Issue': '"<a href=\'https://jira.abc.com/browse/abc-123456\' target=\'_blank\'>\'abc-123456\'</a>","<a href=\'https://jira.abc.com/browse/abc-1234567\' target=\'_blank\'>\'abc-1234567\'</a>"'}
```

Why are my inner strings being escaped?

Comment: Perhaps the escaping is just there for presentation purposes, to show that those particular single quotes are literal.  That is, the actual string does _not_ contain escaped single quotes.

Comment: your `issuestr` has both single and double quotes in it. One of them need/will be escaped in any case when presenting it as a string. When you print the str python defaults to enclose it with single quotes, so they are escaped within the string itself. If for example you dump `jiraissues` to json it will escape the double quotes and leave the single quotes unescaped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join the string without the inner strings being escaped

```
s = ["<a href='https://jira.abc.com/browse/abc-123456' target='_blank'>'abc-123456'</a>", "<a href='https://jira.abc.com/browse/abc-1234567' target='_blank'>'abc-1234567'</a>"]

issuestr = ''.join(s)

print(issuestr)

#Output 
#<a href='https://jira.abc.com/browse/abc-123456' target='_blank'>'abc-123456'</a><a href='https://jira.abc.com/browse/abc-123
```

Is this what you expect?